# When using e.Entity in an EntityDataSource Inserted event, is it good practice to wrap it in using()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I'm doing something with the inserted values during an EntityDataSource's Inserted event, should I wrap `e.Entity` in a `using()` statement? I can't tell. Is that "in context"?

Should it be (as I've seen in other examples):

```
myEntity NewRecord = (myEntity)e.Entity;
myVar = NewRecord.DataValue;
```

Or is it appropriate practice to do:

```
using (myEntity NewRecord = new e.Entity())
{
    myVar = NewRecord.DataValue;
}
```

(Don't think that syntax would be totally correct. Don't want to have to look up how that would work just to ask.)

From the MSDN documentation, all I can gather is that e.Entity is an object that is ... the entity. Helpful. So does it open a new connection and the whole rest of the package that I would assume a new entity would require?

Comment: By way of explicit example: On this page, http://forums.asp.net/t/1621469.aspx/1 , 3rd post down, in    protected void EntityDataSource1_Inserting()    var myTestUupdate = (e.Entity as UBOTest). Is myTestUupdate now in possession of resources requiring disposal? i.e. Is it better practice to encapsulate that within using()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I'd say yes do it.  Best practice?  Yes for sure.  However, the answer is more like "it depends".  As a rule, anytime you use an object that implements `IDisposable` one should wrap it in a using statement unless you plan to keep the object between method invocations.

In the stateless world of the web (MVC) where I tend to live, I try to wrap my `DbContext` in a using statement.  In Winforms/WPF I'm sure there are reasons to persist until some event takes place.  These should be exceptions to the rule.

Comment: So, because e.Entity is "an object that is the entity", and the entity in my case represents a table in a database, the entity does implement IDisposable, always and necessarily, because it must talk to a database in order to be that entity? I'm sorry if it sounds like I'm being unnecessarily convoluted, but I'm not very familiar with object-oriented stuff, let alone .NET, and I feel these are assumptions I can't make.

Comment: @GG2 - The tables themselves do not implement `IDisposable` as you already noticed.  Because of this you can't use a using statement.  If that's what you are trying to do then the answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I'm referring to the entity representing a table, and because it does, it must communicate freely with that table for any given interaction that changes data; and so must therefore always open a connection (thus requiring a dispose to free up resources). And since a new instance of the entity doesn't know whether it will make changes to the table, it will always open a connection (that requires disposing), no? (I'm adding a more explicit (perhaps) example to my original post.)

Comment: @GG2 The user is not required to concern themselves with opening and closing database connections in entity framework.  Object Services manages the connections and opens and closes them as required.  Details can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582.aspx

Comment: @GG2 In other words, I know of no reason to require using statements for SQL connection disposal.  The reason I suggest using a using statement is simply because DBContext requires some kind of disposal because it implements IDisposeable.  As far as what is required I dont know.  A glance with reflector should tell you.

Comment: Except, I do. Thus the best practice of wrapping resources in using() to explicitly free them. For example, per the note on the page you referenced: "When a query method is called, the connection is opened, and it remains open until the ObjectResult has been completely consumed or disposed." What I don't know is whether the entity represented by e.Entity is something that is best handled with a using() statement because it's opening connections, or because its "ObjectResult" isn't being "completely consumed". (I don't yet know what all is happening with all these .NET objects.)

Comment: Not trying to be argumentative. :) With all these objects and entities and resources that must be created to work w/ anything in .NET, I just can't tell what is a "resource" that might be best wrapped in using(), without vast familiarity with all the abstract concepts and which "thing" each .NET object is. So, it sounds like e.Entity is one of those "resources" that is best to explicitly clean up.

Comment: @GG2 - No worries, I understand you are just trying to get to the bottom of this.  Unfortunately your reputation is still too low to chat.  I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish and don't know where to go without a discussion.  Somehow, I still feel like `DbSet` is somehow involved.

Comment: Here's perhaps another way to approach this. What would be the actual syntax for the resource being used in using()? Given the following failed: `protected void EntityDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
 {
  using (XMem NewMember = (XMem)e.Entity)
  {
   _MemberId = NewMember.MemberId;
  }
}` Where the following worked great: `XMem NewMember = (XMem)e.Entity; _MemberId = NewMember.MemberId;`

Comment: Trying to avoid a lengthy "discussion" here, but I often can't help being verbose, because each word has very specific purpose and meaning to me; and not sure I should post these as "answers" to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Using is used when you want to make sure you call the Dispose method when the program execution leaves the scope of the using.

For example say your code might throw an exception and you wanted to make sure it still called Dispose().  A using statement would guaranty it.

So if myEntity implemented iDisposable you would want to use the using statement.  If it doesn't you wouldn't need to, but still could, I think... lol.